# Flash Builder 4.7 compiles project with errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I am upgraiding a loader for external flash game(this loader is already written and it is working, but I have been using previous version of Flash Builder(not sdk!) to write it.
What I need is to see what classes of my code does not exist in the project... For now it just compiles everything with or without errors and does not shows any errors or warnings to me.

I think the example will show what I mean:

I have a working function wich compiles without errors:

```
protected function init(event:Event = null) : void
    {
        Living.movie.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.init);
        this.GamePlayer = Living.movie.parent.parent;
        this.Map = this.GamePlayer.map;
        this.Map.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, this.dispose);
    }
```

I am making changes to this function:

```
 protected function init(event:Event = null) : void
    {
                   NotExistingClassOrVariable = OMGIT will compile and so on;
        Living.movie.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.init);
        this.GamePlayer = Living.movie.parent.parent;
        this.Map = this.GamePlayer.map;
        this.Map.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, this.dispose);
    }
```

and above function compiles without any errors too.... I can write anything inside a function body - it will compile(but it will not work ofcaurse)...

Please help me to solve this problem - trying to solve it already for 8 hours.

And sorry for my really bad english =(

Comment: what kind of project you created in flashbuilder ?

Comment: @Binou Its Action Script Project

Comment: in the properties of the project did you check "enable stric type checking" and "enable warnings" in actionScript compiler tab ?

Comment: Adding to @Binou's questions, are you sure you're testing in debug mode?

Comment: @Binou Yes, stric and warning are checked there.

Comment: @Marcela What do you mean? I need to start IDE in debug mode somehow or what?

Comment: Yes, if your application is compiling but not working, you're probably getting runtime errors. The runtime errors will be shown if you are debugging the application via the IDE. I don't use FlashBuilder, but this article should explain the process: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7f07.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a problem by reinstalling flash builder. I do not know why it happened, but seem it was IDE bug.